# Where is the official documentation for R Markdown YAML frontmatter?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, yaml-front-matter

I can't find the official documentation for R Markdown YAML frontmatter, for example for this option:

```
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
```

I've looked into [R Markdown: The Definitive Guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/) (which, by the way, it's the book linked from the [official R Markdown website](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/index.html)) but it's not there.

I've looked into [R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/), it's hinted at [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/notebook.html) but doesn't look like the official reference.

I've looked into [R Markdown Reference guide](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/rmarkdown-reference.pdf), it's not there.

I've looked into [R Markdown Cheatsheet](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/main/rmarkdown-2.0.pdf), it's not there.

Comment: It was implemented in this pull request https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/pull/1007. There was a comment there that it should have been included in the "R Notebook docs" though I'm not sure where that is or if it ever made it there. It may be an undocumented feature.

Answer (score 3):

There is no official documentation for R Markdown YAML frontmatter because the YAML frontmatter is a collection of metadata and each individual piece of data might or not be used by a piece of software from your tool chain. The mentioned metadata,

```
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
```

is used by R Studio to have the code block output "be shown in the R console instead of inside the source editor". This option might be ignored by VSCode or Emacs.

Comment: Do I have to open another question? Because it was tagged RStudio

Comment: @robertspierre https://rstudio.github.io/visual-markdown-editing/options

Comment: @Christoph uhm no "chunk_output_type" is not there either